# typescript observable subscription undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I make an http request to get some data which I am trying to display in the following:
I have a dropdown select to show `entriesPerPage` and a left and right cursor to switch `page` in my pagination. This works, but when I switch a page it always shows that

> Cannot read property 'page' of undefined

In addition to that I can't show the `totalEntries` or `totalPages` at all, they don't seem to work in data binding either.

component.ts

```ts
  public getArticles(): void {
    this.articleService.getAllArticlesWithPagination(this.paginationResponse.pagination)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.dataSource.data = data.data;
        this.paginationResponse.pagination.page = data.pagination.page;
        this.paginationResponse.pagination.entriesPerPage = data.pagination.entriesPerPage;
        this.paginationResponse.pagination.totalEntries = data.pagination.totalEntries;
        this.paginationResponse.pagination.totalPages = data.pagination.totalPages;

      });
    console.log(this.paginationResponse); // added for this question after comments
  }
```

pagination.response

```ts
export class PaginationResponse<T> {

  public data: T[];
  public pagination: Pagination;

  constructor() {
    this.pagination = new Pagination();
  }
}
```

pagination.ts

```ts
export class Pagination {

  public static readonly DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
  public static readonly FIRST_PAGE = 0;
  public static readonly DEFAULT_TOTAL = 3;
  public static readonly DEFAULT_ENTRIES = 10;

  public page: number;
  public entriesPerPage: number;
  public totalPages: number;
  public totalEntries: number;

  constructor() {
    this.page = Pagination.FIRST_PAGE;
    this.entriesPerPage = Pagination.DEFAULT_SIZE;
    this.totalEntries = Pagination.DEFAULT_ENTRIES;
    this.totalPages = Pagination.DEFAULT_TOTAL;
  }
}
```

`console.log(this.paginationResponse)`
[image]

EDIT: So it seems the `paginationResponse.pagination` is never actually filled with the data of `data`. Interesting is that `data` alone shows the fields of the pagination (totalPages, totalEntries, page, entriesPerPage) in addition to the `data[]` but `data.pagination` shows only those who are defined in the constructor of Pagination.ts (code snipped above). I don't see why it doesn't add the pagination to it.

SOLUTION:
I expected the return in `PaginationResponse` to wrap my object of `Pagination`. I removed the `pagination` from it and instead put the 4 fields in it. So the answers despite being short seems about right.

Comment: This simply means that `this.paginationResponse` is defined but does not have `pagination` property. From this code block it's not enough to determine why it doesn't contain `pagination`.

Comment: It does. I updated my question with the code snippet of the class.

Comment: can you put a console.log somewhere to show paginationResponse

Comment: that does give me: ``PaginationResponse {pagination: Pagination}
pagination: Pagination
entriesPerPage: 5
page: 0``

Comment: Hmm, can you provide a screenshot perhaps? It would be easier for me to read. It would be best to show a screenshot of your `console.log` for `this.paginationResponse` after the `subscribe` part. But this doesn't look like it's in this place. What does `getAllArticlesWithPagination` do? Only sends requests or something more?

Comment: `getAllArticlesWithPagination ` only sends the request with the queryparameters. Added a screenshot of the console.log directly after the subscribe()

Comment: in the above code it looks like you are consoling `paginationResponse` before the observable returns (did that have those properties before this function was called), to see what is being returned you would want to put a console in the subscribe, porbably `console.log(data)` to make sure you get the console before the error is thrown

Comment: If I do console.log(data) all my pagination entries show, including: `totalEntries: 17`
`totalPages: 4` sho. But why doesn't `this.paginationResponse.pagination.page = data.pagination.page;` work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see `data.pagination` is undefined.

Comment: But how can it be? It is the response of my request and in the `console.log(data)` shows the data + pagination.

Comment: I guess you are right. But I don't understand why it isn't mapped to my `paginationResponse.pagination`..